Change array of object value based on another array
const array1 = [
  {
    id: "40",
    alias: "Number",
    name: "Number",
  },
  {
    id: "41",
    alias: "Salary",
    name: "Salary",
  },
];


const array2 = [
  {
    id: "Sum__Salary__U3VtKFVTJTIwRW1wbG95ZWUuU2FsYXJ5KQ__",
    name: "Salary",
  },
  { id: "40", name: "Number" },
];

I want to modify my array2, my 'Salary' id should become "41" in my second array instead of "Sum__Salary__U3VtKFVTJTIwRW1wbG95ZWUuU2FsYXJ5KQ__"
Sharing the snipped which i have tried:
const result = array1
  .filter((array1Value) =>
    [...array2].find(
      (array2Value) => array2Value.name === array1Value.alias
    )
  )
  .map((column) => ({
    id: column.id,
    name: column.name,
  }));
console.log("result: ", result);

The above snippet is working fine, but here I am returning new set of array using map, is there any way where I can replace the values instead of creating new set of array? Looking for good approach to implement this.

Here is the solution using forEach & find high order functions:


const array1 = [
  {
    id: "40",
    alias: "Number",
    name: "Number",
  },
  {
    id: "41",
    alias: "Salary",
    name: "Salary",
  },
];

const array2 = [
  {
    id: "Sum__Salary__U3VtKFVTJTIwRW1wbG95ZWUuU2FsYXJ5KQ__",
    name: "Salary",
  },
  { id: "40", name: "Number" },
];

array1.forEach((item1) => {
  const matchingItem = array2.find((item2) => item2.name === item1.alias);
  if (matchingItem) {
    matchingItem.id = item1.id;
  }
});

console.log("Modified array2:", array2);




You can use forEach Method:
array2.forEach(data2 => {
    array1.forEach(data1 => {
        if (data2.name == data1.alias) data2.id = data1.id;
    })
})



const array1 = [{
    id: "40",
    alias: "Number",
    name: "Number",
  },
  {
    id: "41",
    alias: "Salary",
    name: "Salary",
  },
];


const array2 = [{
    id: "Sum__Salary__U3VtKFVTJTIwRW1wbG95ZWUuU2FsYXJ5KQ__",
    name: "Salary",
  },
  {
    id: "40",
    name: "Number"
  },
];

console.log("Before :");
console.log(array2);

array2.forEach(data2 => {
  array1.forEach(data1 => {
    if (data2.name == data1.alias) data2.id = data1.id;
  })
});

console.log("After :");
console.log(array2);




Thanks! is there any way to avoid multiple forEach? looking for simplified syntax. Can we achieve this through reduce?

@Sameer the only way you can avoid a nested loop is to first create a lookup object from array1 {Salary:41, Number:40..} and then use that on the array2 foreach. but since your arrays are small the nested loop isnt that bad

something like this i meant const lookupMap = array1.reduce((acc,curr) =>(acc[curr.alias] = curr.id,acc),{}); and array2.forEach(e => e.id = lookupMap[e.name]);

As a one-liner:
a2.forEach(x => x.id = a1.find((y) => x.name===y.name)?.id ?? x.id);



const a1 = [{
    id: "40",
    alias: "Number",
    name: "Number",
  },
  {
    id: "41",
    alias: "Salary",
    name: "Salary",
  },
];


const a2 = [{
    id: "Sum__Salary__U3VtKFVTJTIwRW1wbG95ZWUuU2FsYXJ5KQ__",
    name: "Salary",
  },
  {
    id: "40",
    name: "Number"
  },
];

a2.forEach(x => x.id = a1.find((y) => x.name===y.name)?.id ?? x.id);

console.log(a2);




const temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array2))
array2.forEach((elem, index) => {
    console.log(elem?.name)
    for (let item of array1) {
        if (item.name === elem.name && item.id !== elem.id) {
            temp[index]['id'] = item.id
        }
    }
})
console.log(temp)

